# Adjusting solving variable during solve_ivp() process

Tags: python, solver

I am using the solve_ivp() function to solve some equations of motion. More specifically I'm modelling the Social Force Model, where the solve_ivp() is numerically computing the velocity and position of each person in the simulation. Now I have a bit of a weird issue where I'm trying to implement a relatively simple operation within the solving process, but the results are the inverse of what I am expecting.

This code snippet shows the relevant function that is used for the solve_ivp() function.

```
def motion(t, X):
        
        all_forces = Forces(X)
    
        for i in range(N):
            
            # allocate vector dX
            dX[i*MMM] = X[i*MMM+2]
            dX[i*MMM+1] = X[i*MMM+3]
            dX[i*MMM+2] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,0]
            dX[i*MMM+3] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,1]
        
        return dX
```

Then inside the "Forces(X)" function I use the following code to check whether the people are inside the contaminated are and if they are I want to reduce their velocity by a factor:

```
# update pedestrian variables
    for j in range(N):
        
        # check if the pedestrians are inside the contaminated area
        if np.linalg.norm(c[0].pos-p[j].pos[0]) <= c[0].radius:
            p[j].pos[0,0] = X[j*MMM]
            p[j].pos[0,1] = X[j*MMM+1]
            p[j].velocity[0] = X[j*MMM+2]*c[0].weight
            p[j].velocity[1] = X[j*MMM+3]*c[0].weight
        
        else:
            p[j].pos[0,0] = X[j*MMM]
            p[j].pos[0,1] = X[j*MMM+1]
            p[j].velocity[0] = X[j*MMM+2]
            p[j].velocity[1] = X[j*MMM+3]
```

This code is place at the top of the "Forces(X)"  function and afterwards the forces on the people are calculated again based on their position and velocity values.

The results should be fairly  straightforward, since the velocity is just multiplied by a number, but the results dont show that. The problem is that the weights I'm using seem to be used inversely, where a low weight (0.4) increases their velocity and a higher weight (2) decreases their speed. I added 2 gifs to showcase this. Does anyone see why this is happening? I am looking for possible causes within the calculation of the forces, that might be causing this, but wanted to know if its something in the logic of the code that I am overseeing.

This gif shows the result of setting the weight to 0.4, as you can see the velocity increases.
[image: sim_weight_0.4]

For comment from

```
c1_pos = np.array([18,5,7.5])
c1_radius = 3.5
c1_weight = 1.4

# initialize contaminant
c = []
c.append(contaminant(c1_pos, c1_radius, c1_weight))
```

Comment: What happens if you set the weight factor to 1.4?

Comment: They slow down slightly when entering the circle.

Comment: What is the structure of c[0]?  Are you sure that setting weight to 1.4 is the same as setting c[0].weight to 1.4?

Comment: Yes I am sure of that, I added the definition of c to the end of my post

Comment: unless I am missing something c[0].weight is not the same as c[0].weight.

Comment: Are you referring to the last part of the post? I just added that for clarfication about your comment above, because I couldnt add code in this comment section. Normally it's set to 0.4.

Comment: I found the problem. The placement of my updating was wrong. I had to put it in the "motion()" function, because now everytime it calculated new values for the velocity it would save them in the solution before adjusting it according to the weight.

Comment: Please show your solution as an answer and select that answer as a solution, so we can all learn

Comment: Ah sorry I missed this, I will post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found writing the condition in the Forces(X) function did not get the wanted results. What I think happened is it would change the velocity, then based on the changed velocity calculate it's new velocity and update it. Since one of the forces in Forces(X) is calculated by taking the difference between the current velocity and the "desired velocity", which is a constant, it meant that the calculated force becomes bigger. The solution was to put the checking statement in the motion(t, X) function instead like I have shown below. This code just adds a couple extra if statements to check for various radii.

```
    def motion(t, X):
        
        all_forces = Forces(X)
    
        for i in range(N):
            # check if the pedestrians are inside the contaminated area
            if np.linalg.norm(c[0].pos-p[i].pos[0]) <= c[0].radius:
                dX[i*MMM] = X[i*MMM+2]*c[0].weight
                dX[i*MMM+1] = X[i*MMM+3]*c[0].weight
                dX[i*MMM+2] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,0]
                dX[i*MMM+3] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,1]
            elif np.linalg.norm(c[1].pos-p[i].pos[0]) <= c[1].radius:
                dX[i*MMM] = X[i*MMM+2]*c[1].weight
                dX[i*MMM+1] = X[i*MMM+3]*c[1].weight
                dX[i*MMM+2] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,0]
                dX[i*MMM+3] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,1]
            elif np.linalg.norm(c[2].pos-p[i].pos[0]) <= c[2].radius:
                dX[i*MMM] = X[i*MMM+2]*c[2].weight
                dX[i*MMM+1] = X[i*MMM+3]*c[2].weight
                dX[i*MMM+2] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,0]
                dX[i*MMM+3] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,1]
            else:
                dX[i*MMM] = X[i*MMM+2]
                dX[i*MMM+1] = X[i*MMM+3]
                dX[i*MMM+2] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,0]
                dX[i*MMM+3] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,1]
            

        return dX
```